# App sending multiple sms in receipt of call/sms

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, sms, intentservice

My app is Designed that when active it should send 1 sms in receipt of a call/sms.
for some people though, multiple sms get sent out in receipt of 1 call/sms.
Im not sure why this is happening ? and it only appears to happen to some people, but i'm aware that it could be a potential bug that could happen to all users.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Do I need to put in a if+ shared pref boolean somewhere ?

**SmsReceiver**

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private String tempMessage = "";


@Override
// when OnRecieve recieves the correct Broadcast. in this case when a sms is recieved
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    String action = intent.getAction();

    //Toast.makeText(context, "onReceive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    if (action.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        //action for sms received


        // the actual sms will come in the form of a a intent
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();


                    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

                    editor.putString("incomingNumber", phoneNumber);
                    editor.commit();

                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();



                    if (!tempMessage.equalsIgnoreCase(message)) {


                        if (phoneNumber.contains("+")) {


                            //TODO after receiver is finished set CHmessageSent pref boolean to false.
                            Boolean messageSent = preferences.getBoolean("CHmessageSent", false);
                            if (!messageSent) {

                                Intent smsIntent = new Intent(context, sendSmsIntentService.class);
                                context.startService(smsIntent);
                                //Toast.makeText(context, "startIntent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                            Log.i("SMS_RECEIVER", "senderNumA: " + phoneNumber + "; message: " + message);


                        }
                    }   

                } // End For loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReciever", "Exeption smsReceiver" + e);
        }
    } // END IF ction.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")

   }

 }
```

**SendSmsIntentService**

```
public class sendSmsIntentService extends IntentService {


private String phoneNumber;
private String defaultSms = "";
private String sms;


//Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.

public sendSmsIntentService() {
    super("sendSmsIntentService");
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    phoneNumber = preferences.getString("incomingNumber", "null");



    defaultSms = getString(R.string.drivesafesms);
    sms = preferences.getString("message1",defaultSms);

    Log.i("SMS_RECEIVER", "senderNumb: " + phoneNumber);

    //


    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, sms, null, null);


        if (!preferences.getBoolean("CHmessageSent",false)) {
            editor.putBoolean("CHmessageSent", true);
            editor.commit();
        }

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.receivedCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.smsFailed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("CALL_RECEIVER", "senderNum: " + phoneNumber);
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: You are not checking `phoneNumber` for null in your IntentService, that might create an issue down the line.

Answer (score 0):

IntentService does work on a single thread. If your broadcast is called twice in a quick succession before your `CHmessageSent` is set to true, 2 messages will be sent out.

I'd recommend you move this check to inside the IntentService:

```
Boolean messageSent = preferences.getBoolean("CHmessageSent", false);
if (!messageSent) {
    //Send SMS
editor.putBoolean("CHmessageSent", true).apply();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Ill try this out now. in this case which is  better .apply(); or .commit();

Comment: No real difference except that `apply()` doesn't return a value and is a bit faster.